# using variables from layout in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

hii i have a jade layout file.
The code is as follows

```
html.no-js(lang='en')
  //<![end if]
  head
    script(type='text/javascript')
        var x = "datablabla";
```

And i have a jade file that extends this layout.
How can i access that x variable??

```
extends ../layout

head
    script(type='text/javascript')
        alert(1);
block headerContent

block bodyContent
    h1 Wellcome to the blabla
    p #{x} // undefined
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. You're declaring `x` in a client side script block, and Jade doesn't execute those to make any code/variables declared in such a block available within the template.

Longer answer: you *can* add embedded JS code in your Jade templates like this:

```
- var x = "datablabla";
```

You can reuse that `x` variable in both the client side part, and in your other Jade template:

```
// layout
- var x = "datablabla";
head
  script
    var x = '#{x}';

// other
extends layout
...
block bodyContent
  h1 Welcome to the blabla
  p #{x}
```